# bash cannot find mvn command after install

Tags: bash, centos, software-installation, wget, maven

I tried to install Maven on CentOS 7, but afterwards typing `mvn -version` in the terminal results in `bash: mvn: command not found...`.  **How can I fix this so that I can call maven from the CentOS 7 terminal?**

The steps I took are from [this tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/install-apache-ant-maven-tomcat-centos-76-5/), and they are also described explicitly and entirely as follows:

```
wget http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip

unzip apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip
mkdir /opt/maven
mv apache-maven-3.3.1/ /opt/maven
ln -s /opt/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
gedit /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
Add the following contents to /etc/profile.d/maven.sh :
    #!/bin/bash
    MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
    PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
    export PATH MAVEN_HOME
    export CLASSPATH=.

Save and close the file. Then: 
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Log out or reboot the computer. Then (with username and results shown this time):

```
[root@localhost ~]# mvn -version  
bash: mvn: command not found...  
[root@localhost ~]# mvn --version
bash: mvn: command not found...
[root@localhost ~]# echo $MAVEN_HOME  
/opt/maven
```

Note that I did not install Ant.  Also, the tomcat installation was done separately long ago.

---

**EDIT**

---

As per @MarkPlotnick's advice, I tried the following, with the following results:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mv /opt/maven /opt/maven.bak
[root@localhost ~]# mv /opt/maven.bak/apache-maven-3.3.1 /opt/maven
[root@localhost ~]# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (lotsnumbersandletters; 2015-03-13T13:10:27-07:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "versionnumber", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Try `mv /opt/maven /opt/maven.bak; mv /opt/maven.bak/apache-maven-3.3.1 /opt/maven` and see if things work after that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Please see my **EDIT** to my OP above.  Does this mean it works now?  If so, please feel free to submit it as an answer and I would be happy to accept it.  I would be curious to hear your explanation of what happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you cited said to do this:

```
wget http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/maven/maven-3/3.2.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.zip
unzip apache-maven-3.2.3-bin.zip
mv apache-maven-3.2.3/ /opt/maven
```

This will result in `/opt/maven/bin`, `/opt/maven/lib`, etc.

What you did was slightly different:

```
wget http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip
unzip apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip
mkdir /opt/maven
mv apache-maven-3.3.1/ /opt/maven
```

This resulted in `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin`, `/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/lib`, etc.

When you do `mv x /y/z`, where x is a directory, three different things can happen:

- if `/y/z` doesn't already exist, the entire tree rooted at `x` is moved to `/y/z`.
- if `/y/z` already exists and is a directory, the tree is moved to `/y/z/x`.
- if `/y/z` already exists and is not a directory, `mv` will output an error message and won't move anything.